# TGT expiring if we are using app1 and not using other

Tags: spring-security, cas

we have a question about ticket-granting tickets expiration policy. We are using cas authentication. The TGT expires after 2 hours whereas java session exiperes after 30 minutes.Our problem is that if a user works only using a web application more than two hours and than tries to use another web application, the ticket-granting ticket is expired and so the user must re-login, although he can work in the first web application.

Is there a way to renew ticket-granting ticket while the user is working in the first web application??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, short of doing some magic, as of CAS 3.4 (when I was looking into a very similar problem) the answer is no.

If you absolutely have to implement this feature, the best idea I've run across (a co-worker came up with it, not me) was to have every page of your apps use Javascript to "ping" your CAS server (a simple AJAX request that doesn't care about the return will work), and implement a custom TGT Expiration Policy that keeps track of the last ping-back and expires the ticket if the last ping was more than X seconds ago.  However, this approach requires a considerable amount of hooks into the CAS framework and I would recommend against it.  I'd provide code but it has been too long since I really dug into CAS's internals.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. How to implement custom TGT Expiration Policy and extend TGT. Plese post some ideas or code. Sothat i can decide which direction to go. I will appreciate ur help.

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help, but the implementation took me weeks of digging through CAS source code to even figure out, and was very fragile (hence our decision to go a different direction).  That was months ago, and I can't remember all of the hoops I had to jump through to get it working, and there were a lot of them.  The best advice I can offer is that if you're looking to implement SSO across multiple apps with an inactivity timeout, CAS isn't a viable option.

Comment: Than you. May i know what are other options to choose. and a different direcion you have used. If you dont mind to tell me.

Comment: That depends entirely on the nature of the applications you are securing, and probably would warrant its own, new question.